# Add data to two tables using one controller

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, postman

I am doing a project using react.js and Laravel. After the clicking the button I need to save the data in two table. I have two tables in Database which are aproduct_sc and shopping_cart. I need to use one controller and one function to insert the data to above two table. Because, I am using one API for this purpose.

The ShoppingCart Controller I used,

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\ShoppingCart;
use App\Models\Customer;
use App\Models\AProduct;
use App\Models\AProductSC;

class ShoppingCartController extends Controller
{
   function addScart(Request $req)
   {
    $shoppingcart=new ShoppingCart;
    $shoppingcart->cust_id=$req->input('cust_id');
    $shoppingcart->save();
    return $shoppingcart; 

    $aproductsc=new AProductSC;
    $aproductsc->quantity=$req->input('quantity');
    $aproductsc->aprice=$req->input('aprice');
    $aproductsc->scart_id=$req->input('scart_id');
    $aproductsc->aproduct_id=$req->input('aproduct_id');
    $aproductsc->save();
    return $aproductsc;
   }
}
```

The ShoppingCart Model I used,

```
 <?php

 namespace App\Models;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ShoppingCart extends Model
{
   use HasFactory;
   protected $primaryKey = 'scart_id';
}
```

The Aproductsc Model I used,

```
 <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AProductSC extends Model
{
  use HasFactory;
}
```

API I used,

```
Route :: post('addScart',[ShoppingCartController::class,'addScart']);
```

I tested this using Postman and it shows a error that "NotFound". How can I solve this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: First of all, in your `addScart` method, the code after first `return` will not be executed, so delete or comment this line. Do you get a `404 NotFound` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you provided, the syntax is wrong.

From `Route :: post('addScart',[ShoppingCartController::class,'addScart']);`

Change to

`Route::post('addScart',[ShoppingCartController::class,'addScart']);`

Also some suggestions to improve the code. If you have to do with multiple models, use `repositories`. Considering renaming your variables & files as clean as possible. Also your primary key just call it `id` and you don't have to override it.

Comment: Does it say still 404? Which endpoint are you calling on postman?
If you registered your routes in api.php you need to add /api before

Comment: I think there should be error in my "addScart function" because I am not pretty sure about that coding.

Comment: Can you figure it out?

Comment: Use public function addScart ()
Can you please give more information about the error because i cannot figure out what's going on without knowing

Comment: I have two tables in Database which are aproduct_sc and shopping_cart.  After I click the button called"add tocart" the both  aproduct_sc and shopping_cart tables should fill.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the above suggestion, It is a kind of strange for me to return two times in a function

And I suggest you to use DB::transaction() to have control over your database insertion